# why Overlapping comparisons always evaluates to true in following

Tags: c++, qt

I do not understand why following code has warning stating that overlapping comparisons always evaluate true. Next statements are never executed.

```
QVariant MainModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
{
    if (!index.isValid())
        return QVariant();
    if ((role != Qt::DisplayRole) || (role != Qt::EditRole)) // always evaluates to true warning, but why?
        return QVariant();
    if (index.column() == 0 && index.row() < m_values.count()) // this is never executed warning
        return m_values.at( index.row() );
    else
        return QVariant();
}
```

Comment: If `role` is equal to `Qt::DisplayRole`, it can't be equal to `Qt::EditRole` at the same time (and vice-versa), hence, at least one of those conditions is `true`. `true` or anything = `true`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Assuming `QT::DisplayRole` and `QT::EditRole` have different values** (otherwise why would you compare to both?) then let's think about this...

If `role` is equal to one, then it **must** not be equal to the other. Therefore, one of the two conditions will be true. And since this is an OR, that means the whole expression will be true.

The only case this won't happen is if `QT::DisplayRole == QT::EditRole`. Did you mean to use an AND (`&&`) instead of an OR?